# why I cannot download documents If subfolder name of document library contains “+” symbol

Tags: 2010, 2007, document-library

I am using sharepoint 2007 portal.
In document library I have created one folder and named it as "Cards + Payments".
I am able to upload document in that folder but when I try to download, it is throwing error.
Error popup message is - "The Internet address "path of the document" is not valid"
But when I remove + symbol then it gets downloaded.
What is this issue and why it is occured?
If anyone knows about this please let me know.

Comment: If you want to be on the safe side, use only A - Z, 0 - 9, _ and - for file names and folder names. Everything else can mean trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check this link out: [Information about the characters that you cannot use in site names, folder names, and file names in SharePoint](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231/en-us). You will see that the "+" is not allowed. Its seems that SharePoint have removed the illegal character for you and that is why it works.